# Azure logic app extract 2nd line from body

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a body message body which contains an important service name in the body of the message which is plain text. I need to extract that whole line into a new field. how can this be achieved in Azure logic app.

Sample data

```
%%%
DB-Service-Name
Line1
Line2
```

I only need to extract the 2nd line from the message body in a new field Service-Name

Comment: Split the string up by a new line and then get the second item in the resulting array.

Comment: Its the 1st time I am using logic app which action to use for splitting the string

Comment: No action, you need to use an expression.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#split

Comment: okay got it. but how to call the body variable in a split function ?

Comment: If no one else has answered, will try and get you an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use split action as mentioned by @ skin. I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps I followed,

- Created logic app as shown below and assigned

```
%%%
DB-Service-Name
Line1
Line2
```

it in a initialize variable.

[image]

- Next taken another initialize variable as shown below to split lines based on new line and the expression is
  **split(variables('Service'),'\n')**

  Note: Make sure you add this expression in code view as logic app by default append '\'.

[image]

Next taken another initialize variable as shown below to get second value and the expression is,
**split(variables('Service-Name'),',')[1]**

[image]

logic app ran successfully as shown below.
[image]
Output of final initialize variable.
[image]

Comment: On my actual payload its not splitting correctly I cannot share the exact data

Comment: I just made a small change `split(variables('Service-Name'),'\n')[1]` and it worked for me

Comment: Glad it's working now for you also

Comment: Flow is identical just one change will modify my comment